# How to Add JavaScript To ASP.NET Dropdownlist (Template Filed) Of Gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

How to add JavaScript on ASP.NET Dropdownlist, pass that Dropdownlist Id to that same JavaScript function which is called? How to do the same for Dropdownlist which is a template field of Gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add onchange event in dropdown if you do not need anything from database/server end

```
<ItemTemplate> <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="BindEng(this);" Height="16px" Width="179px"> <ItemTemplate>
```

Add RowDataBound event to gridview and access dropdown for each row and assign javascript to it, here you can access data of datasource if required for javascript function.

```
protected void GrdViewUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("YourDropDownListID") as DropDownList;
        //The statment below will pass the client id of drop down to function in javascript
        ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "YourjavascriptMethodCall('" + ddl.ClientID + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Adil Thanks for the solution to[ Add Javacript To ASP.NET Dropdownlist (Template Filed) Of Gridview?]. this worked.

Comment: we can also define it in source level of the control as below.   <ItemTemplate> <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server" onchange="BindEng(this)" Height="16px" Width="179px">  <ItemTemplate>

Comment: Thanks, Yes its better if we just need to pass this in BindEng. The code in answer is useful when we have to pass something variable. I will update my answer .

Answer (score 0):

To add javacript to dropdown and pass the selected value-->
ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "BindEng('"+ddl.SelectedValue+"');");